# Upper Case in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am trying to create a view with Majors and Minors w/ upper case, but Oracle keeps giving me an error. What am I doing wrong?

CREATE VIEW A5T4 AS

SELECT StudentID, Major1, Major2, Minor

FROM A5

WHERE UPPER(Major1, Major2, Minor)

ORDER BY StudentID;

The error is: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to display only majors and minor that are in upper case?

Comment: `UPPER` only accepts a single parameter & there's no condition in your WHERE-clause. Try `SELECT StudentID, UPPER(Major1) Major1, UPPER(Major2) Mayor2, UPPER(Minor) Minor FROM A5 ORDER BY StudentID;`

Comment: I am trying to display the majors and minors in upper case. So would the condition be every single major? Do I have to list them? The majors are for example Fin or Mis... how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the where clause. If you want your fields with upper case, use the function in the SELECT clause, not in the WHERE clause.

Try this  :

```
CREATE VIEW 
   A5T4 
AS
SELECT 
   UPPER(StudentID) AS "StudentID", 
   UPPER(Major1) AS "Major1", 
   UPPER(Major2) AS "Major2", 
   UPPER(Minor) AS "Minor"
FROM 
   A5
ORDER BY 
   UPPER(StudentID);
```

Comment: It would probably be correct to also collapse the case in the `ORDER BY UPPER(StudentId)` to have the result match the values presented in the view.

Comment: It would also be nice if the view gave the columns names so they could be referenced.

Comment: This is what I did:

CREATE VIEW A5T4 AS
SELECT StudentID, UPPER(Major1), UPPER(Major2), UPPER(Minor)
FROM A5
ORDER BY StudentID;

but now it says SQL Error: ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"

Comment: No problem :) Can you mark my answer as correct  please?

Comment: Please be aware that using double-quoted mixed-case aliases means that any time we want to reference a column we need to use double-quotes and that exact case e,g, `where "Major1" = 'HISTORY'`.   This will cause  confusion for application developers.  Likewise, including the ORDER BY in a view is poor practice.  Sorting should be left to the client side.